# Motivation?: Lie algebra and algebraic group Cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-algebras, homology-cohomology, algebraic-groups, group-schemes

This is just an apriori question to get a motivational heuristic idea:

If an algebraic group G *(more generally, G an affine group scheme)*, is connected over an algebraically closed base-field k.  Then are there relationships between its rational cohomology and the cohomology of its lie algebra?

In short, what information does each give about G (if these differ)?

What articles written on the subject?

Comment: Have you had a look in Jantzen's book on algebraic groups? I recall it covering the basics and giving some good references.